# My dotnet maui project just broke. AppShell cannot find LoginPage and set it as its ContentTemplate. It all worked when I started the project

Tags: .net, mvvm, maui, xml-namespaces

I have a problem in dotnet maui intelisense. The debugger says:Error XFC0000 Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace:MAUI.Views:LoginPage". The problem disappears when I add new Page, for example NewPage.xaml. It can find the one I added but not the ones that were previously there. Thank you for your time.

I tried building and restoring project multiple times. It just says LoginPage cannot be resolved. I checked multiple times that LoginPage is in the Views namespace.

Code:

LoginPage.xaml.cs:

```
using MAUI.ViewModel;
namespace MAUI;

public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage(LoginPageViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

When I change namespace from MAUI to MAUI.Views the method InitializeComponent() throws eror: The name InitializeComponent does not exist in its current context. As of the rest of the pages that are in namespace MAUI.Views I can now use them in XAML. Looks like intelisense does not know about them but when I compile project and run it everything works fine.

Comment: (1) Add to question all relevant code. (2) Are you able to successfully build the project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am able to build project. I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the LoginPage's namespace is MAUI not the MAUI.Views. So the LoginPage.xaml.cs should be:

```
using MAUI.ViewModel;
namespace MAUI.Views;

public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage(LoginPageViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

And the LoginPage.xaml shoul be:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Maui.Views.LoginPage">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the reference in the AppShell.

The page is in the 'MAUI' namespace:

```
namespace MAUI;

public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
```

So this makes it 'MAUI.LoginPage'. At the top of your AppShell put this:

```
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MAUI"
```

Then in the AppShell page itself you can do this:

```
<ShellItem FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" x:Name="LoginPageShellItem">
  <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoginPage}" Route="LoginPage" />
</ShellItem>
```